# Can I use Delphi LiveBindings to create a two-column 'Name','Value' editable list from a TObjectBindSourceAdapter?

Tags: delphi, livebindings

Using Delphi XE7 and FireMonkey I am looking at simple ways of displaying (and editing) some object property values in a TGrid. I have followed the tutorial [showing how to bind TGrid columns to object properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Tutorial:_Using_TAdapterBindSource_and_the_LiveBindings_Designer) and using a `TObjectBindSourceAdapter` I have a neat, single row grid populated from my one object as they show in the example.

However, I will only ever have one object in the grid (a single row) so I would really like to turn my grid data through 90 degrees to give me two columns - a fixed 'Name' and an editable 'Value'. My object properties would then be listed vertically (effectively like the Object Inspector view).

Is there a LiveBindings way of doing this, or should I use another control such a TListView? I'm new to LiveBindings!

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain what is wrong with this question?